# Return all results within a 2km,5 and 20km radius of a specific lat/long point?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using the below query for calculation but I don't know how to pass
the radius first time I need 2 km and in second query need 5 km and so
on:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM pwd_roads AS r
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(r.geom, ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakePoint(75.083333, 29.583333), 4326)) < 8
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: You're working with a degree based CRS. You need to change this, if you want to pass km-wise distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is technically correct; `ST_Distance_Sphere` returns distance in *meter*, though (`< 8` doesn't make sense in the context of your question).

Note that with PostGIS version > 2.2.0 this function is called `ST_DistanceSphere`, and AFAIK most legacy function signatures will be removed at some point in the 3.x release!

---

**However:**

For proximity searches, better use `ST_DWithin` to get index enhanced performance.

Depending on your actual goal it might make sense to query for spatial proximity only once and work with a derived attribute from there. Since this query would repeatedly create the reference point, I outsourced that expression into a CTE:

```
WITH
    pt AS (
        SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(75.083333,29.583333), 4326)::GEOGRAPHY AS geog
    )

SELECT  *,
        CASE
            WHEN ST_Distance(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geog, FALSE) <= 2000 THEN
                2  --within 2km distance
            WHEN ST_Distance(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geog, FALSE) <= 5000 THEN
                5  --within 5km distance
            ELSE
                20 --within 20km distance
        END AS proximity
FROM   pwd_roads AS a
JOIN   pt AS b
  ON   ST_DWithin(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geog, 20000)
;
```

This retrieves all geometries in `pwd_roads` that are within 20km of the reference point and assigns an attribute (`proximity`) value (corresponding to the *km* range) to each geometry based on actual distance.

To work with *meter* as unit in `ST_DWithin` this uses the `GEOGRAPHY` type; while the type has other uses, `ST_Distance(<GEOGRAPHY>, <GEOGRAPHY>, FALSE)` is equivalent to `ST_DistanceSphere`.

Note that the reference point is cast to `GEOGRAPHY` within the CTE.

Comment: Can i use like this select * from my_table where ST_Distance_Sphere(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(76, 29),4326))<2000 for 2 km distance?

Comment: @sumitkundan sorry for the late reply; yes, you could. note that the above is optimized for performance, while a simple distance filter is probably the worst performing option.